# SQL Get data in this year

Tags: sql, date

i have a DB with a atribute "Date" which is a string ...

its format is:
"Jan 5 2014 6:26 PM" 
and would like to get the number of rows where the date is this year.

already know how to convert the date:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, 'Oct 23 2012 11:01AM')
```

i found this code but I do not know how to join the two

```
select * from datetimes2
where dtm2 >= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
and dtm2 < DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE))
;
```

Now I do not know how to do what I want :(

Comment: And your database is...? And this year is...2014?

Comment: do you mean get data..from date and date+1 ??

Comment: do you mean get data of current year ?

Comment: My DataBase is EmailsRecebidos and the atribute where i save the Date called Data...

and a want current year...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you looking for ?

```
DECLARE @datetime DATETIME = 'Jan 5 2014 6:26 PM' 
SELECT 
* 
FROM datetimes2
WHERE [Date] >= CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, @datetime) AS VARCHAR) + '-01-01')
  AND [Date] <= CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, @datetime) AS VARCHAR) + '-12-31')
```

This will get the records for complete year 2014. Hope this helps!

Comment: already figured out how to do the last 30 days:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmailsRecebidos
where Data >= DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

As simple as (assuming SQL server, given convert() )

```
select * from mytable where year( convert(datetime, date) ) = year( getDate() )
```

?